# Issue in routing for MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to implement routing in My MVC application.

```
routes.MapRoute("View",  
               "View/ViewCustomer/{id}",  
               new { controller = "Customer", action = "DisplayCustomer", 
id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

above code is not redirecting to CustomerDetail controller.

I want to use above url for calling it.
http://localhost/View/ViewCustomer/

Comment: You route is for a controller named `CustomerController`, not `CustomerDetailController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change code like this

```
routes.MapRoute("View",  
               "View/ViewCustomer/{id}",  
               new { controller = "CustomerDetail", action = "DisplayCustomer", 
id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

**It should be  controller = "CustomerDetail".**